# Hello World Apex trigger Field names

Tags: apex, trigger, community

As this is my first step to learn SFDC. I am stuck with a question at the first step itself. As I was going through video lessons and I am unable to understand how this works as Lead field does not contain FirstName and LastName fields (Under setup).

Also, when i checked the fields in Build>Leads>Field section i can see First Name (with space) and Last Name( with space) under Salutation field. Then how come salesforce trigger is updating name field when the trigger says l.FirstName = 'this'; Please help me understand as i have already spent 2 hours searching for above details :(

```
    trigger HelloWorld on Lead (before Update) {
      for (Lead l : Trigger.new){

        l.FirstName = 'hello';
        l.LastName = 'world';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Object viewer UI  does not show actual API Names for certian fields on certain standard object. Lead being one of them,

[image]

If you want to see actual API names, Open Developer Console->Open -> Lead.obj , it displays a table for APINames of the field that you can use in your code.

[image]

A field has 2 main Attributes, 1 Label , and 1 API Name.

Label can have spaces, API_Names cannot. API Name is used everywhere in code.

Comment: Thank you Pranay. this helps.